# UiPath custom ocr engine

Tags: uipath, uipath-api

Recently UiPath announced that now you can create your own OCR engines - [link](https://forum.uipath.com/t/document-understanding-new-human-robot-levels-available/246253)

I am trying to create one, but can't find any information on how to do it, the only documentation I found about that is this - [OCR Contracts](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/about-the-uipathocrcontracts)

But there is no information on how to build and release one, so it would be available for people.

So is there any examples or information about it?

Comment: https://github.com/UiPath/Document-Processing-Code-Samples/blob/master/Samples/SampleActivities/Basic/OCR/SimpleOCREngine.cs